# Sending email of Post in Wordpress with special characters

Tags: php, wordpress, email, post, special-characters

I have made a plugin that will send out an email every time a new post is published in Wordpress to the admin (eventually this will go to subscribers).  Within my plugin I have a email template in table format which is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Email test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"> 
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20" valign="top"></td>
                        <td width="560" valign="top">%%CONTENT%%</td>
                        <td width="20" valign="top"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</body>
</html>
```

I string replace the %%CONTENT%% with the content from the post.  I have tried running the content through various functions and filters including: apply_filters, htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities() with no success.  When I receive the email in Outlook it has weird characters in it.  My post contains some special characters like £, &, “, ’ and the degree symbol °C.

This is the plugin code:

```
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    global $post;
    $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $to[] = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $name, $email );
    $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );

    $content = $post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

    $html_content = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/email_components/email.html');
    $message = str_replace('%%CONTENT%%', $content, $html_content);

    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset="UTF-8' . "\r\n";

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

So my question is how do I get these characters to safely display correctly in the email subject and email body?  Many thanks! Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end after trying many different options I solved this by using the wordpress loop to output my email content:

```
$thepost = new WP_Query('post_type=news&p='.$post_id);
if($thepost->have_posts()) {
    while($thepost->have_posts()) {
        //runs once to get the one queried post
        $thepost->the_post();
        $content = wpautop(get_the_content());
    }
}
```